# O que significa orientado a documentos?

Tags: terminologia, paradigma-de-programação

Já vi que existem inúmeras terminologias orientadas, como orientado a objetos, orientada a agentes, orientada a aspectos, orientada a classes e vários outros.

Mas o que vi recentemente é orientado a documentos, como dito na descrição do MongoDB:

> MongoDB (do inglês humongous, "gigantesco") é uma aplicação de código aberto, de alta performance, sem esquemas, **orientado a documentos**.

- O que significa orientado a documentos?
- Quais as principais qualidades/diferenças desse paradigma?
- Esse termo, somente é aplicável a banco de dados? Se não, onde mais ele pode ser utilizado?

Comment: É para contrapor banco de dados relacional. Ele usa o conceito de documento, não de tabelas ligadas.

Comment: Se não me engano, o CouchBase também é documental

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> O que significa orientado a documentos?

No contexto do MongoDB significa que dados são armazenados em formato de objeto complexo, como no exemplo abaixo:

```
{
   title: "MongoDB: The Definitive Guide",
   author: [ "Kristina Chodorow", "Mike Dirolf" ],
   published_date: ISODate("2010-09-24"),
   pages: 216,
   language: "English",
   publisher: {
              name: "O'Reilly Media",
              founded: 1980,
              location: "CA"
            }
}
```

As duas queries a seguir são *equivalentes*:

```
SELECT * FROM BOOKS WHERE pages >= 216;  // Transact-SQL
```

e

```
db.getCollection("BOOKS").find({pages: { $gte: 216 } }) // BSON
```

Perceba que o objeto segue a notação JSON. Isso é por padrão: O [MongoDB utiliza JSON para troca de dados](https://www.mongodb.com/json-and-bson), e [BSON](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/bson-types/) - uma versão binária, extendida do JSON - para permitir descrições de tipos de dados e operadores lógicos.

> Quais as principais qualidades/diferenças desse paradigma?

Tabelas de SGBDs tradicionais são estruturas bidimensionais (colunas x linhas). Isso significa que você precisa decompor um objeto complexo em estruturas aninhadas (ex. `NotaFiscalCabecalho`, `NotaFiscalItens`) antes do armazenamento - e, inversamente, coletar registros de várias tabelas para recompor o objeto.

Com um banco de dados que armazena objetos complexos, este passo é desnecessário.

> Esse termo, somente é aplicável a banco de dados? Se não, onde mais ele pode ser utilizado?

Eu diria que não. Qualquer estrutura que trabalhe com serialização de objetos complexos - armazenamento em disco de arquivos JSON, por exemplo - pode ser considerado uma estrutura de documentos (de acordo com a definição do MongoDB).

Comment: E em relação a desempenho (tempo de resposta, capacidade de expansão) vs um relacional? Alguma diferença quando se armazena objetos?

Comment: Você falou em serializaçãoe desserialização de objetos complexos, lembrei de uma discussão arquitetural sobre sincronismo de informações em um sistema de força de vendas, se iríamos fazer o sincronismo usando documentos ou se seria por linhas.

Comment: @leonardopessoa depende da aplicação. E depende muito. MongoDB não é a bala de prata, mas também não deve ser retirado da conversa para sempre. De modo geral, informações que são armazenadas hierarquicamente são melhor representadas como documentos, mas caso o grafo de dependência seja muito complexo e menos árvore, o modelo relacional funciona bem demais

Comment: @leonardopessoa Se sua aplicação lida com objetos complexos então existe uma economia significativa no seu processo, já que você pode ignorar rotinas de decomposição/composição. Quanto ao tempo de resposta, minha *experiência pessoal* indica que diferenças são irrelevantes para estruturas simples, e considerável se você utiliza pesquisas em estruturas.

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado Existem operandos que permitem *patching* (adição/edição parcial) de documentos, o que é útil neste caso.

Comment: @OnoSendai curti essa ideia de _patch_. Quem sabe saia na terceira versão do sincronismo? :-)