# Em que tipo de aplicação posso usar MongoDB?

Tags: banco-de-dados, mongodb, nosql

- Usar **MongoDB** em todo tipo de aplicação é ruim?
- Existem tipos de aplicação em que é mais recomendado e tipos onde não é recomendado usar um NoSQL?

Comment: Leitura interessante: https://medium.com/@Pinterest_Engineering/sharding-pinterest-how-we-scaled-our-mysql-fleet-3f341e96ca6f#b433, "How we sharded"

Comment: Tudo bem, sei que MySQL é uma boa escolha, apesar de preferir Postgres, mas quero saber sobre o MongoDB, em que momento é ideal e em que momento não é recomendado utilizar. Valeu pelo link.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Claro que é ruim, e isso vale para qualquer tecnologia. Dá para usar em qualquer aplicação? Provavelmente sim, a questão é o quanto o resultado será bom e quanto esforço terá que fazer.

Você precisa de transações? Esqueça qualquer NoSQL. Para suprir isso as pessoas estão recriando controle de transações na aplicação, provavelmente de forma muito pior. Ou estão "deixando pra lá", afinal na maioria dos casos funciona. Tem aplicações que pode funcionar na maioria dos casos, tem aplicações que precisam funcionar em todos os casos.

[image: Fiat 147 todo detonado andando pelas ruas]

Precisa de relações? Vai sofrer com qualquer NoSQL. E vou dizer uma coisa: a maioria das aplicações precisam de relações, e para não usá-las as aplicações estão criando dados redundantes e trabalhando a consistência na aplicação. Isso pode ser bom ou ruim. A performance provavelmente sofrerá.

O MongoDB tem transações só dentro do documento, e se eu não estiver desatualizado, com limitações (já melhorou, mas ainda não resolve de fato). Sua aplicação é orientada a documento? A maioria não é.

Não vou falar de NoSQL como cache porque não é o caso do MongoDB, mas invalidação de cache é um problema muito difícil e geralmente aceita-se uma solução mais ou menos.

Por isso que sempre digo que um banco de dados relacional deveria ser a primeira escolha, até que ele não seja mais adequado. Inclusive atualmente os relacionais proveem características não relacionais que se integram bem e tem-se o melhor dos dois mundos.

Não dá para dizer de forma genérica o que é melhor, depende do padrão de uso.

## Mitos

- NoSQL é melhor para grandes volumes de dados

  Pode ser... em algumas situações. Mas se precisa dos recursos citados acima, de que adianta ser melhor em algo e não fornecer o necessário?
- NoSQL tem melhor desempenho

  Cada tipo tem alguma vantagem se faz muito uma determinada operação, mas não é bom para tudo.

  Há casos que o MongoDB será muito rápido para escrita e leitura (é verdade que provavelmente não precisaria dele com este padrão).

  Escrita é algo lento e não tem milagre. É possível minimizar alguns efeitos, especialmente a amplificação, mas não mudará absurdamente sem comprometer a durabilidade.

  A maioria das aplicações fazem muito mais leituras que escritas. Mas se as leituras forem isoladas o MongoDB vai bem, o problema é quando começa fazer relações de documentos.
- NoSQL escala bem

  É verdade. Se não precisar de relações e transações. Escalar esses mecanismos é muito complicado em qualquer modelo adotado. Se abandoná-los o modelo baseado em SQL escala fácil (pelo menos os bons produtos).

O modelo relacional adota o [ACID](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/203857/101), o NoSQL (na verdade o correto seria NoRel) adota o [BASE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eventual_consistency). Precisa saber qual é mais importante. Se precisa do ACID, esqueça NoSQL.

Já existe modelo híbrido baseado em NoSQL. Não sei dizer se os resultados são bons, mas tenho certeza que tem desvantagens.

Existem vários relatos de dramas passados porque adotaram o MongoDB por modismo e não por necessidade. Todo mundo acha que é o Facebook quando são no máximo uma indústria com processos complexos que não podem falhar e baixos volumes de dados e operações. O Facebook tem necessidades e vantagens que você não tem.

O MongoDB pode ser útil em aplicações secundárias ou nas principais quando a atividade principal é focada totalmente em documentos não estruturados.

Sugiro ler sobre o [CAP theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAP_theorem).

Dizem que versões novas do MongoDB tem transações além do documento. Pode ser, mas lembremos que eles já disseram isso antes quando não era verdade e chegaram falar que tinham colocado em versão recente e não aconteceu de fato. Mesmo que agora tenha, se usar isso ele perde alguma característica que as pessoas apreciavam. Eu já vi gente falando que a MongoDB estava acabando com o CAP theorem, eu ria muito.

Veja mais:

- [Quais são os tipos mais comuns de bancos de dados para aplicações web?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/205171/101)
- [Como escolher entre NoSQL e SQL?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/122452/101)
- [NoSQL é tão problemático quanto parece?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/14533/101)
- [O que é um banco NoSQL? Como é o seu funcionamento?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/96409/101)
- [O que faz um JOIN ser ruim em banco de dados?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/216855/101)
- [O que significa orientado a documentos?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/219364/101)

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 5):

Eu gosto bastante do [mongodb](/questions/tagged/mongodb), estou mais acostumado com ele. Ele é muito rápido, também é o banco de dados [nosql](/questions/tagged/nosql) mais utilizado no mundo, com uma comunidade bem grande.

No mongo você trabalha com `collections` e `documents`, como não é [sql](/questions/tagged/sql) você utiliza a linguagem dele [bson](/questions/tagged/bson) que é baseada no [json](/questions/tagged/json).

É importante salientar que um banco NoSQL é muito bom porém não elimina os Dbs relacionais em SGDB, afinal não se deve excluir décadas de experiência comprovada. Em alguns casos será melhor um do que o outro, mas existem casos, como o meu onde utilizo de forma hibrida os dois tipos de banco de dados.

O [blog](http://www.itexto.net/devkico/?p=1621) desse cara  é muito legal para entender algumas coisas bem importantes sobre o mongoDB e ajuda você entender alguns cuidados sobre o MongoDB de forma bastante equilibrada. Mais coisas podem ser vistas [aqui](http://www.itexto.net/devkico/?p=1983)

Como o MongoDB permite você inserir campos em qualquer ponto de seu documento, isto é, possui schema-free, por isso deve existir bastante cuidado para criar sua arquitetura de dados devido a esta flexibilidade.

Um caso legal para usar o Mongo é em formulário dinâmico onde o usuário pode criar campos aleatórios dependendo da necessidade dele quando não sabemos que campos serão criados então ele pode ser criado no documento de acordo com a necessidade.

Answer (score 5):

Minha resposta é baseada em experiências práticas.

Mongo armazena JSON. Se o seu aplicativo estiver lidando com muitos objetos JS e você deseja persistir esses objetos, use o MongoDB. Isso tornará suas camadas DAL e MVC muito finas, porque elas não estão empacotando todas as propriedades do objeto JS e tentando forçá-las a uma estrutura (esquema) na qual elas não se encaixam naturalmente.

**Velocidade de escrita?!?!** 
Cara não é usando MongoDB que você terá essa vantagem, se realmente você precisa resolver um problema de velocidade de escrita de seus dados use outro banco tipo o Voldemort.

**Escalonamento?!?!** 
Quem precisa disso na prática?! Facebook?! A não ser que você esteja criando algo para competir com o Facebook, porquê você precisaria escalonar!? :)

***Se você quiser usar o MongoDB blz, mas não espere que ele faça magica pra você.***

Comment: Eu uso MongoDB também a um bom tempo. Mas nunca fui a fundo pra saber realmente na pratica, considerando realmente um banco complexo como o do Facebook. Não estou criando algo para competir, mas algo que envolve tantos dados quanto... Obrigado!

Answer (score 3):

O NoSQL é mais indicado para aqueles sistemas que tenham necessidades maiores de armazenamento e desempenho. Existem vários tipos de banco NoSql, o **MongoDb** é um banco Nosql orientado a documento. 
Esse tipo de banco tem uma performance incrível para escrita e não tão boa para leitura.

Nesse projeto, postado no github, podemos ter uma comparativo de performance contra o Mysql
https://github.com/webcaetano/mongo-mysql

Em outra palavras, o MongoDB é recomentado para projetos que necessitem de muita escrita.

Outra grande vantagem é a facilidade de escalonar o banco para vários servidores, talvez essa deva ser maior motivo por diversas empresas adotarem esse tipo de banco hoje em dia.