# O que é o MongoDB e por que eu, enquanto dev front-end, deveria adotá-lo em vez do bom e velho MySQL?

Tags: banco-de-dados, mongodb, nosql

Eu tenho ouvido comentários de outros devs pra migrar pro MongoDB pra criar minhas aplicações.

Como e por que eu deveria fazer isso?

Existe uma interface pela qual eu posso manipular os dados, etc.?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

É um mecanismo de banco de dados dentro do espectro chamado NoSQL, ou seja, ele não busca organizar as informações de forma tabular e relacionada. Pode ler mais sobre em [O que é um banco NoSQL? Como é o seu funcionamento?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/96409/101). E ver que NoSQL pode não ser uma boa ideia para maioria das aplicações, mesmo que algumas pessoas achem que sim: [NoSQL é tão problemático quanto parece?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/14533/101) e [Como escolher entre NoSQL e SQL?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/122452/101). Pode saber mais sobre o MongoDB em [Em que tipo de aplicação posso usar MongoDB?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/274320/101).

Para quem é desenvolvedor *frontend*, de forma geral, não precisa saber sobre isso ou qualquer outro banco de dados que é algo usado no *backend*, e se a parte do *backend* exigir você saber de algo, ela é muito mal feita.

Claro que o MongoDB poderia ser útil em algum cenário de *frontend*, mas não nessa que as pessoas falam e costumam usar. Em geral quando fala de *frontend* a pessoa está falando de web e aí não tem como usar o MongoDB nessa parte. Mas se for *frontend* desktop, ou eventualmente mobile, o MongoDB poderia ter alguma função, assim como poderia usar um SQLite ou outro banco de dados para armazenar algumas informações localmente que não faça sentido colocar no servidor ou que faça sentido ter nos dois lugares, provavelmente por otimização.

Comment: Complementando a resposta do @Maniero, acredito que as principais interfaces para manipulação de dado que não seja por linha de comando é o Compass e o Robo 3T.